# Dynamic Menu from multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic

I would like to create a menu from multiple JSON files.

Please see the following: https://jsfiddle.net/varJSFiddle/teghqov0/10/

The desired output would be a dynamic menu that looks something like:

```
<ul class="filter-menu-wrapper">
    <li class="filter-menu is-active" id="filter-menu_01"><span class="filter-category">Type<i class='cstm-icon-glyph cstm-icon-glyph-plus'></i></span>
        <div class="filter-options">
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter="">any</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".TypeHuman">Human</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".TypeBlue">Blue</span>
            <span class="filter-option thefirst" data-filter=".TypeRed">Red</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".TypeSpirit">Spirit</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-menu" id="filter-menu_02"><span class="filter-category">Special<i class='cstm-icon-glyph cstm-icon-glyph-plus'></i></span>
        <div class="filter-options">
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter="">any</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialFireflies">Fireflies</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialButterfly">Butterfly</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialFoxFire">Fox Fire</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialSmoke">Smoke</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialSakura">Sakura</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialFire">Fire</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialEarth">Earth</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialWater">Water</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".SpecialLightning">Lightning</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-menu" id="filter-menu_03"><span class="filter-category">Clothing<i class='cstm-icon-glyph cstm-icon-glyph-plus'></i></span>
        <div class="filter-options">
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter="">any</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".ClothingLightKimono">Light Kimono</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".ClothingMaroonYukata">Maroon Yukata</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".ClothingBlueKimono">Blue Kimono</span>
            <span class="filter-option" data-filter=".ClothingGreenYukata">Green Yukata</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm looking to combine the JSON files and use the "trait_type" as the category and the "trait_value" as the filter. Here's a link to an individual file: https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQFkLSQysj94s5GvTHPyzTxrawwtjgiiYS2TBLgrvw8CW/1

Comment: The goal is a dynamic menu that doesn't have any duplicates.

Comment: add required output image also

Comment: Thank you MAYUR, I already have the image output / display working. I just need to build the menu dynamically (as it's currently hard-coded).

Comment: did you mean jsfiddle format like your above html code

Comment: Yes! Exactly, sorry I'm new here so perhaps I did not articulate my question correctly.

Comment: I would like the jsfiddle to output a dynamic menu to look like the html code I wrote above (which is hard-coded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need like below output , try it, comment if query

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // 1.) create an attributes (trait) array
    // 2.) loop through the items, check if the trait is already in the array, if not then add it
    // 3.) loop over attributes array and create the menu items off that.
    
    var loopFunction = function(dataIsLoading) { // the loop
        
        var itemURI = "https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQFkLSQysj94s5GvTHPyzTxrawwtjgiiYS2TBLgrvw8CW/"
        
        var myArray = []; // create an array to capture all traits
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            
            $.getJSON(itemURI+i, function(data) {
                
                var menuItems = "";
                var headings = "";
                var subheadings = "";
                var dataFilter = "";
                
                $.each(data.attributes,function(index,entry) { // i (index), e (entry)
                    
                    headings = entry.trait_type;
                    subheadings = entry.value;
                    dataFilter = entry.trait_type + entry.value;
                    dataFilter = dataFilter.replace(/ /g, '');
                    
                    menuItems += '<li class="category"><b>' + headings + '</b>: <br/> ';
                        menuItems += subheadings + ', ';
                        menuItems +=  dataFilter;
                    menuItems += '</li>'

                    myArray += entry.trait_type + ': ' + entry.value;
                });
                
                $('#myList').html(menuItems);
                $('#dump').html(myArray);
                //console.log(myArray);
            });
        }
    };
    
    $.when(loopFunction()).done(function() {
        
        var secondaryFunction = function(secondary) { // the loop
            
            // alert("it's done, sort and display");
            
        }
        
        secondaryFunction();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id ="myList">
 
</ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant MAYUR, it looks correct to me. I will test it out in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I just tested it but the submenu items should contain "ALL" values for that particular trait. For example, Type should contain: Human, Blue, Red, Spirit. To show this in code it would look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Type:
        <ul>
            <li>Human</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Spirit</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry MAYUR, I don't know how to write clean code in this editor.

Comment: Type:
Human, TypeHuman    what should be

Comment: Type: Human, Blue, Red, Spirit, TypeHuman, TypeBlue, TypeRed, TypeSpirit.

==

They are all of the sub-values of the trait "type".

Comment: If you would like more data, just increase the value of: for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) { to something like for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

Answer (score -1):

MAYUR, I ended up with the following. It works perfectly however it is a little slow. If you have any tips on improving the speed, let me know:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // 1.) create an attributes (trait) array
    // 2.) loop through the items, check if the trait is already in the array, if not then add it
    // 3.) loop over attributes array and create the menu items off that.
    
    var getItemData = async function(id) {
        
        const itemURI = "https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQFkLSQysj94s5GvTHPyzTxrawwtjgiiYS2TBLgrvw8CW/"
        return await $.getJSON(itemURI+id);
    }
    
    var loopFunction = async function(dataIsLoading) {
                    
        var items = {};
        var promises = [];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                
            // Get data and add to promises array:
            promises.push(getItemData(i));
        }
        
        // Wait on all promises:
        return await Promise.all(promises).then(function(promise) {
            
            // Loop over each returned promise:
            $.each(promise, function(index, data) {
                
                // Loop over attribute data:
                $.each(data.attributes, function(index, entry) {
                    
                    let menuParent = entry.trait_type;
                    let menuChild = entry.value;
                    let menuParentItem = {};
                    
                    // Check for menuParent:
                    if (items.hasOwnProperty(menuParent)) {
                        
                        // Get menuParent:
                        menuParentItem = items[menuParent];
                    }
                    
                    // Check for menuChild:
                    if (!menuParentItem.hasOwnProperty(menuChild)) {
                        
                        // Add menuChild:
                        menuParentItem[menuChild] = menuChild;
                    }
                    
                    // Update items object:
                    items[menuParent] = menuParentItem;
                });
            });
            
            // Return items.
            return items;
        });
    };
    
    $.when(loopFunction()).done(function(items) {
        
        // Loop over all items creating the markup.
        var menuItems = '';
        
        $.each(items, function(menuParent, menuChildren) {
            
            menuItems += '<li class="menuParent"><b>' + menuParent + '</b>: <ul>';
            
            // Loop over menuChildren.
            $.each(menuChildren, function(menuChild, menuChildValue) {
                
                menuItems += '<li class="menuChild">' + menuChild + '</li>';
            });
            
            menuItems += '</ul></li>';
        });
        
        // Render menu items.
        $('#myList').append(menuItems);
    });
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id ="myList">
 
</ul>
```